# SNI.dll not found

Tags: c#, .net

Hi when we copy our app to a new system we get the following error:

```
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Failed to load ...\Ticketing\x86\SNI.dll ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden
```

But after we install the SSMS it works. My question is, what does the SSMS install that is needed. Because I just want to install that component and not the complete ManagementStudio.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/installing-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install the [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and than it worked. Thanks for Hans Passant for pointing me in the right direction.